# Error of connection to the MS SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server

Why I can't will be connected to the MS SQL server?

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.5.jre8-preview</version>
</dependency>
```

Java Code:

```
import java.sql.*;

try { 
      // Load the SQLServerDriver class, build the 
      // connection string, and get a connection 

      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
      String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.35\\SERVER-SQL;" + 
                             "database=MainDataBase;" + 
                             "user=user;" + 
                             "password=rdthnb137"; 
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
      System.out.println("Connected.");

      // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data. 

      String SQL = "SELECT * from history";  
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

      // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it. 

      while (rs.next()) {  
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));  
      }
    }  
    catch(Exception e) { 
      System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
      System.exit(0);  
    }
```

> The connection to the host 192.168.1.35, named instance server-sql failed. Error
>   : "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and in
>   stance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  F
>   or SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is runni
>   ng on the host.

[image: Image of setup of port of a copy of the server]

I am connected from the local machine. The firewall is switched off.

The MS SQL server 2000 with the Service Pack 4 updating is installed.

When using `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.35;database=MainDataBase;", "user", "rdthnb137");` error:

> 22, 2017 1:49:58 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection Prelogi
>   n
>   WARNING: ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 6684e1dc-9950-4082-8fa9-73d5bf4b38b6
>    Server major version:8 is not supported by this driver.
>   SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver. ClientConnectionId:6684e1d
>   c-9950-4082-8fa9-73d5bf4b38b6

Comment: Looks like the Server is not running

Comment: @Jens Open the image in the question, the server is running.

Comment: whether your DB and application is running in same machine?

Comment: @PorkkoM No, the server is installed on other machine. I am connected through a local area network.

Comment: Did you checked , your sqlserver driver is on your java path ?

Comment: @Shaon I connected it by means of Maven. Incorrectly?

Comment: Oh, sorry , you are getting "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". May be your remote machine is blocking your access due to a firewall in that remote host?

Comment: The firewall is switched off. It is connected through RDP and other program which uses the database.

Comment: give it a try : 
"jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.35:1434\\SERVER-SQL;" +

Comment: @Shaon The port number 1434\SERVER-SQL is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.20;instance=SERVER-SQL;DatabaseName=MainDataBase";
    String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "sa";
    String password = "sa";
    try {
      Class.forName(driver);
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
      System.out.println("Connected to the database!!! Getting table list...");
      DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
      rs = dbm.getTables(null, null, "%", new String[] { "TABLE" });
      while (rs.next()) { System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")); }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.close();
        rs.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`

Try :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
```

And Instead of

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.35\\SERVER-SQL;" +"database=MainDataBase;"
```

try :

```
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://192.168.1.35\\SERVER-SQL:1433;DatabaseName=MainDataBase
```

Comment: You can write a complete request with the user and the password? Or farther to leave as well as was?

Comment: I think , you spelled wrong there ,
in case of DatabaseName you put database 
and in case of jdbc.sqlserver you put   sqlserver.jdbc

Comment: I wrote `Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");` and `String connectionUrl = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://192.168.1.35\\SERVER-SQL:1433;DatabaseName=MainDataBase" + "user=user;" + "password=rdthnb137"; ` I received `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver`. What is the matter?

Comment: Look please at the changed question.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
try {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    try {

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Raumfahrt", "root", "");

    String insertStrM ="INSERT INTO Raumfahrt.Mitarbeiter VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement prestmt = con.prepareStatement(insertStrM);

    prestmt.setInt(1, m.getmID());
    prestmt.setString(2, m.getMname());
    prestmt.setString(3, m.getMname());
    prestmt.setInt(4, m.getMabt());

    prestmt.executeUpdate();

    }catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.print("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: if the driver can't be found

Comment: Give please the reference in Maven to your driver.

Comment: i got the jar in my project. without Maven

Answer (score 0):

I know `1433` is default port but can you specify this port number in your connection url after ip addr `192.168.1.35:1433` and give it a try?

Comment: jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.35:1433\\SERVER-SQL; The port number 1433\SERVER-SQL is not valid.